# sqlite step back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I found that the common way for scrolling forward through a result set is using sqlite3_step():

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    // do something with the row
}
```

Is there a way to scroll backwards the result set, like going one step back or accessing a previous row using its ROWID?

Somewhere I have read that you can retrieve each record of the result set by its ROWID, but I can't figure out how.

If there is no such way for retrieving arbitrary rows in the result set, I will like to know whether it would be a bad practice or just a technologic limitation the reason for it.

Comment: Just curious why would you need to do that?

Comment: Hey why do you want to scroll backwards.. If want to access a particular row, you could use your primary key value in the query, for accessing that particular row.. for more info try this [link](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-loading-data-as.html)

Comment: I thought that, if such thing existed, it could be faster to re-use a statement rather than executing a new query for each row when I eventually need them and only at the cost of not freeing some memory.

Comment: pretty sure sqlite3_step doesn't execute the query over and over again. the query is executed by a sqlite3_prepare func, and the result stored in the 'statement' data structure. my guess would be that sqlite3_step() simply moves through the result set.

Comment: I was assuming the same, so I thought that should exist something similar to sqlite_rewind in PHP for seeking back to the first row in the given result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was going through the functions in the sqlite3 framework since I couldn't find any documentation online and found this:

```
sqlite3_reset(statement)
```

I didn't test, but since it takes a sqlite3_stmt just like sqlite3_step() does I assume it rewinds the result set back to the beginning.