# Is there a way to undo SQLite3 step call in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

The system I'm working with uses an SQLite3 database as a background log storage with each entry as a two-column entry : |time|data|. Replaying the log is as simple as preparing a statement to get all entries, and each `sqlite3_step()` call returns the data at time.

Since then, we've attempted to instrument specialized tools to advance and skip as we've needed. Now, we find ourselves in a situation where we need to go backwards by one or more entries. Is there a way without resetting and/or generating a new query to undo the entry-advancement that happens with `sqlite3_step()`?

`sqlite3_reset()` isn't an appropriate solution as this returns the database pointer back to the first entry in the database. I am looking to go back to the immediately previous entry of the last `sqlite3_step()` call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite step back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018285/sqlite-step-back)

Comment: Save the data from the rows you've already seen in your data structure of choice, and use that to look at prior records.

Comment: For some of these, we're talking on the order of GB to TB of data; we didn't want to pre-read because of the overall slowdown and resource footprint for some of the tools using this data.

With regard to the "sqlite step back" duplication: `sqlite_reset()` is not an option as it takes you back to the first entry in the database. I'm looking to go to the immediately previous-retrieved entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way without resetting and/or generating a new query to undo the entry-advancement that happens with `sqlite3_step()`?

No, as of the current version (3.27.2), there is not.  SQLite3 provides only forward-only result sets.

You seem to be aware already of the possibility of resetting a prepared statement via `sqlite3_reset()`, but I think you appreciate that this is not the same thing as stepping backward, even in combination with stepping forward through the results again, contrary to the [speculation presented in answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7042955/2402272).  Resetting abandons the current result set, and subsequently stepping the prepared statement again causes a new query to be performed, with *those* results being retrieved.

If you want to be able to access the data from a previous result row after stepping past it and without performing a new query, then you need to capture and retain it in some kind of local data structure. Depending on your needs, that might not have to be *all* the data you've read.  On the other hand, if you have some other reason than re-reading the data for wanting the result set cursor to be moved backward then you'll need to find another way to achieve whatever purpose that is supposed to serve.

Comment: Thank you for that. Yes, I did read the latest documentation, and when I couldn't find it, I speculated either it wasn't possible or I somehow missed it. Originally, I was hoping to avoid capturing previously read data. There were a handful of error cases created by such an approach (in our application, not with SQLite3 itself). But it looks unavoidable given the current requirements. Thank you for your insight!